# An automatic script to check if inline installation for chrome extension is working

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, automation

I'v been looking for an automatic solution to check if inline installation for google chrome extension is working.
does any one know's how can i check this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be no **automatic solution**, according to [inline installation](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/inline_installation), the installation process must be completed with user participation.

> To actually begin inline installation, the `chrome.webstore.install(url, successCallback, failureCallback)` function must be called. This function can only be called in response to a **user gesture**, for example within a click event handler; an exception will be thrown if it is not.